# Rails 5.1.0.beta1 "bundle update rails" has gem conflict

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upgrade

I just cant upgrade rails beta version. 
My current rails version is 5.0.2 and would like to upgrade to 5.1.0.beta1 version.

ruby -v 

`ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]`

bundle update rails

```
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/........
Fetching version metadata from http://rubygems.org/..`
Fetching dependency metadata from http://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    coffee-rails (~> 4.1.0) was resolved to 4.1.1, which depends on
      railties (< 5.1.x, >= 4.0.0)

    rails (~> 5.1.0.beta1) was resolved to 5.1.0.beta1, which depends on
      railties (= 5.1.0.beta1)

    sass-rails (~> 5.0) was resolved to 5.0.6, which depends on
      railties (< 6, >= 4.0.0)
```

bundle update

```
Fetching https://github.com/megetron/active_merchant_tranzila.git
Fetching https://github.com/megetron/active_shipping.git
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/........
Fetching version metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Fetching dependency metadata from http://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    coffee-rails (~> 4.1.0) was resolved to 4.1.0, which depends on
      railties (< 5.0, >= 4.0.0)

    devise was resolved to 4.2.0, which depends on
      railties (< 5.1, >= 4.1.0)

    rails (~> 5.1.0.beta1) was resolved to 5.1.0.beta1, which depends on
      railties (= 5.1.0.beta1)

    sass-rails (~> 5.0) was resolved to 5.0.6, which depends on
      railties (< 6, >= 4.0.0)

    web-console (~> 2.0) was resolved to 2.3.0, which depends on
      railties (>= 4.0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading this correctly, you need to remove the version constraint of `coffee-rails` in your `Gemfile` because it is incompatible with Rails 5.1.x.

Comment: had to install cofee-rails with --pre option: gem install cofee-rails --pre as you suggested. it has a pre release installation for beta versions of rails. another issue was that I had to remove the sass-rails which didnt had a pre installed version.

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your terminal

```
gem update rails
bundle update
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the devise gem from the repository as they have not released a rails 5.1 version yet (it will probably happen very soon).

In your Gemfile replace the devise line with the following:

gem 'devise', github: 'plataformatec/devise'